# Issue about SearchTextField

Tags: swift, search, uikit, textfield, uisearchbar

I am doing a filtering operation using UITextfield. As it should be, if textfield.isEmpty = true, I run the getCharacters() function that I created in the viewModel, while in the other case I run the function that I wrote the filtering logic for. All operations are running as they should, but there is a problem. In this problem, after the textField performs the first search and deletes it, it needs to run the getCharacters() function again, but it continues to show the results of the last search on the TableView screen. I will also share the source codes of the relevant parts and the screenshot of the problem in the attachment.
[image: All characters are reloading in my tableView]
[![I can do filtering properly][2]][2]
[![When the textfield is empty, it does not reload all characters in my table view. It stucks at the previous search result.][3]][3]

As you can see, I can do filtering as i want.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNqwr.png
But when i delete the texts in the textfield, it does not reload all cells in my table view.
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFshl.png

```
extension CharactersViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Yeni metni oluştur
    let textToEnter = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) ?? ""
    
    if textToEnter.count < 3 {
        // Textfield tamamen boş ise
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.viewModel.getCharacters()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    } else if textToEnter.count >= 3 {
        // Metin uzunluğu 3 veya daha fazlaysa
        self.viewModel.searchCharacters(with: textToEnter)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    print(textToEnter)
    return true
}
```

}